# I can't use response.getWriter() for Initialize about PrintWriter object in JSP declare script

Tags: java, html, jsp, response

I can't use response.getWriter() for Initialize about PrintWriter object in JSP declare script

Hi, I am currently practicing making web bulletin boards with JSP.

But there was a problem, and I asked you a question.

I don't know what's wrong with the code typing, so can you check the code?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Why **not upload images** of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5221149)

Comment: please share code in code format... not in image format...

Comment: Okay! I'll share code in code format!

Answer (score 1):

In JSP, there are 3 types of scripting elements:

```
<%! this is a declaration %>
<% this is a scriptlet %>
<%= this is an expression %>
```

Implicit objects, like `response`, are not available in a *declaration* element. The code in the question should be in a *scriptlet* element.

However, JSPs come with multiple implicit objects, like `response`, and one of them, is:

```
Variable Name  Type                         Semantics & Scope
=============  ===========================  =============================================
out            javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter  An object that writes into the output stream.
```

Which means that the statement you're trying to write is redundant and will fail, since variable name `out` is already declared.

Comment: Then there will be no problem if I choose another variable name(example: 'script' ) instead of 'out', right?

Comment: Whoops.
That code cannot be used within that syntax because the 'response' is an implicit object without using 'out'! Now I get it. Thank you!

Comment: @learner So the answer helped you? You found it useful? Then please up-vote it. --- The answer covered your question? Then please accept it, so others can see that your question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post store.'       What should I do when this phrase occurs?

Comment: Answer some questions to earn rep. :-) The 15 rep limit doesn't apply to *accepting* answers, which you do by clicking the check mark to the left of the (best) answer.